# How is Ubuntu able to send alerts to external e-mail addresses?

Tags: server, cron, email

I am trying to understand the procedure of sending email. I have configured a crontab to send system alerts to my external email and it is working fine. However, I didn't configure any SMTP server on this machine, but still the system can send alerts to external email. This machine is a fresh install and connected to the internet only.

Can anyone help me understand how the system is able to send emails?

Comment: How did you "configured a crontab to send system alerts to external email"? Care to share the steps you made? I'm also interested in this!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This happens because Ubuntu desktop and server has by default (at least on 16.04 and onward) `postfix.service` enabled and running. You can confirm this by issuing the following command in terminal:

```
systemctl --type service --state running | grep postfix
```

The sending of mail works because postfix does a simple DNS lookup for the MX record for the domain the mail is destined for. The receiving server simply takes the mail it got sent and maybe does a few checks on it and puts it on the receivers inbox. So no SMTP configuration is needed to send an email.

Comment: Thanks Videonauth, that's true but how it is working without configuration. Even no one has configured it.

Comment: It is working because it acts like an email-programm, it just tells the receiving server 'Here, I have a mail for the user known by this address'. In fact you can even send out emails without giving a senders name or address if you wish so and have the right knowledge. All the receiving server does is verify the user exists, maybe run a spam check and antivirus on the mail and then put it into the receivers inbox.

Comment: You could probably flesh this out, and help clear up the OP's confusion, by explaining that postfix will do a DNS lookup for the MX record of the domain the email is destined for and simply send the mail to that server. Everything else is down to the mail exchanger of the domain you are sending to.

Comment: The question is tagged [tag:server], but your answer refers to Ubuntu desktop.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson:  does not really matter, the server install has postfix by default as well. Alone for the fact it send internal emails to root@localhost for cron jobs and their success or failure.

Comment: It should be noted that if this machine has a dynamic public IP, there's a good chance that many other mail servers will reject mail from it as a potential spam source. He's lucky that the server for his email doesn't have this blocking enabled.

Comment: There is no postfix on default Ubuntu Desktop 18.04

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is, because I for sure not have installed it, running on 18.04 desktop, and have it running here.

Comment: Thanks to all dears I got the point.

Comment: @Videonauth: it is not installed by default, just test it in a VM. Something else might have pulled it for both you and the OP